# React Native Firebase Auth return null

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

Im doing a expo app, with a login authentication, but my authUser is returning null and I could not find the reason

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
            console.log(authUser)
            if (authUser) {
                navigation.replace('Home');
            }
        })
        return unsubscribe
    }, [])
```

Can someone help?

I've tried use firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged but no success :(

Comment: Take out the `return`? See [Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)